# How do I limit mail attachments?

Tags: attachment

I have a written code that extracts data from an excel sheet. For each supplier in the list it creates an email to them, and adds the contents of a folder. It works seamlessly. The loop works, the attachments are added, the email is sent, all good.

Until.....there are too many attachments in the folder. I'm using the following to add all attachments:

```
Filename=dir(folderpath)
While len(filename)>0
.attachments.add (filename)
Filename=Dir
Wend
```

As I say, this works when there aren't too many attachments. Is there a way to count the number of files in the folder first? Or something that counts the attachments as it adds them?

What I hope to achieve is something along the lines of:

> if attachment count>10 create new mail and continue

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Just thought maybe count files in folder then if over, say 25 for example then zip before adding. Is this possible?

Comment: Ive managed to find a way to count the files in the folder prior to adding as attachment
using this code:

Do While filename <> ""
count = count + 1
filename = Dir
Loop
ActiveSheet.Range("G11").Value = count
If count > 25 Then
'THIS IS WHERE THE ZIPPING WOULD OCCUR
Else
'CONTINUE WITH PROCEDURE
End If

just the zipping of folder contents now if anyone can help
Thanks